# Can't export signed applications

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Eclipse workspace with two Android apps and two Android libraries - the Facebook SDK and my own library. When I try to create APK files, I *sometimes* get the error "Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1".

I went through all SO answers to similar questions, but nothing works:

1. The Facebook SDK library references a jar the wrong way, so I fixed that.
2. I've cleaned the build. Many times.
3. I've deleted the bin folders.
4. This is happening on multiple development machines, but just in case - I've deleted the workspace and started over.

The only fix I found for this was to retry over and over until it works. Other than dropping Android and doing only iOS and Windows Phone versions, what can I do? It's impossible to develop anything this way.

UPDATE:
On one of the computers, I get alternating errors, sometimes it's the Dalvik error, another time it complains it can't export ...\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar .

UPDATE 2: 
The Eclipse log (.metadata/.log) shows details of the exception:

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2013-04-12 00:14:59.163
!MESSAGE Export Wizard Error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:312)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:296)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:233)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:751)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:269)
... 4 more

!SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2013-04-12 00:14:59.163
!MESSAGE Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
!STACK 0
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:751)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:269)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:296)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:233)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Comment: I faced some problems with exporting my application which uses Facebook SDK too. For me it seems so that the problem simply vanished but for a few days I wasn't able to export signed/unsigned version at all. Eclipse simply crashed on me without any message. This was on OSX 10.8.2 with all the latest updates installed on Eclipse.

Comment: I wonder if there's anyone at Google that deals with such issues. It's impossible to commit to any Android deadline like this.

Comment: Everytime which I had that problem, it was because of some of the libraries which I was using in my apps. For example once I had problem which was caused by v4 support library, because it was included in other libraries which I was using. The thing here is, you need to be very careful with the libraries. If you have some other imports in your projects source tree , like Dependecies or something similar to this.If I were you I was going to back up my code, and try to delete some stuff / build and try until it works. The reasons may be many more.

Answer (score 8):

1. Disable Menu -> Project -> Build Automatically.
2. Menu -> Project -> Clean...
3. Menu -> Project -> Bulid All

Worked for me to export signed application package

Comment: This did it somehow, along with an extra Clean afterwards. Thank you.