# Exporting android app fails

Tags: android, eclipse

When I export my finished app, I get an error message[image: Failed to export application]

My keystone file is fine. There's no message in the console or Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **clean the project** and export it again.  You can also close Eclipse and then try again.  Eclipse tends to get in a funky state sometimes.

Steps to clean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16886633/2543138

Comment: I cleaned several times, restarted Eclipse, even rebooted my Mac. Always the same,tried more than 10 times

Comment: have you tried to export it unsigned to see if you will receive any errors?

Comment: I have tried 3 unsigned exports now, which fail as well. The error message is however every time different. Something in the style: Failed to export application
/Users/cr.../my.../bin/classes/drawable/arrowup48.png (No such file or directory). However the object itself exists in res/drawable

Comment: Nobody can help? I reloaded everything in SDK Manager, but problem persists. I get "Failed to export application
/Users/.../my.../bin/classes/com/my.../MyTaxiControlActivity$27.class (No such file or directory)", but this file perfectly exists when I check in Finder. Maybe Eclipse is corrupted and I should reinstall?

Comment: are you running the latest version of ADT?

Comment: Finally I recreated the whole project by moving all objects into a new project. Eclipse can be surprisingly annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Review your library build path. Perphaps that your libraries are repeated?

Comment: You mean java Build Path? There's nothing double